# Add a round-half spherical edge to a cylinder surface

Tags: modeling, edges

I have the following cylinder:

[image: The cylinder I want to modify]

And I want to turn the selected area (as seen in the pic) into a half-sphere similarly to this [picture](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_RKF_hJBtDbg/Sa_858kk6YI/AAAAAAAAEBw/zrtE-lx4uRo/s800/Untitled.png). Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but in most situations, for speed, I would construct this component the other way round: cut a sphere in half, and extrude the flat side to create the cylindrical extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to turn on snap to vertexes first (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).

1. In orthographic view, move 3D cursor to face where you will add sphere (select face of cylinder > <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to set 3D cursor to selected).
2. Add UV sphere with settings of your choosing.
3. Cut sphere in half where it will join (<kbd>Z</kbd> key to set the viewport shading to wire-frame, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to box-select half the sphere, then delete it by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> to remove faces).
4. Move sphere into object (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> if you're bringing it down to align it).
5. Resize sphere with <kbd>S</kbd> (vertex-snap it to the edge of cylinder).
6. *Remove doubles* (button in tool shelf on the left) to get rid of the duplicated vertices.

Here is the process in an animated gif:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Nice answer. Take a look at the markdown in your answer to see how I formatted the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Oh, thank you, and cool. How did you do that? Sorry, I'm quite new to this thing.
Edit: I figured it out. Thanks! I wasn't sure how to see the revisions!

Comment: just click the [edit] button. then look at the source. The keybord shorts are simply wraped in `<kbd>` tags. We have something of a [style guide](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/251/2217) on the meta.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the area where you want to add the semisphere (the same selected vertices in your picture).
2. Move the 3D cursor to the center of the selection.
3. Move the camera so that you're looking at the area from the side.
4. Select the left-most vertex of the previously selected area.
5. Use the spin tool to generate an 90 degree arc. You should get something like this:
   [image]
6. Move the camera to the top of the cylinder.
7. With the vertices of the arc selected, use the spin tool again, now rotating 360 degrees and using as many steps as the number of vertices on the face of the cylinder. The result should look like this:
   [image]
8. Select everything, and use "remove doubles".

Comment: Do you know a quick way to place the cursor to the middle of the selection?

Comment: With Shift+S, then *Cursor to Selected*.